# Calculating gear ratio for leadscrew

Tags: calibration, lead-screw

My calibration at my printer is okay. When I try to move 10 mm, it's exactly 10 mm.

But I want to know what is my precision for Z-axis.

(*not posting the link of the product maybe it's not okay for the platform*)

**Spec for leadscrew:**

- Lead screw diameter: 8 mm
- Screw pitch: 2 mm
- Lead of thread: 8 mm

[image: calculator page]

My question; is my gear ratio 4:1 or 1:4? It's giving different results.

Comment: [This answer](/a/10597/) gives insight in leadscrews.

Comment: In my experience, with decent stepper drivers (e.g. A4988), sticking to full steps for Z axis does not seem to be important (doesn't seem to make any difference to print quality).

Comment: My question is not just for 3D printers, I'm thinking about modifying to high precision CNC :) Thanks in advance

Comment: In short: It's 1:1, and your "pitch" for that calculator is 8 mm. Pitch and lead are frequently confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lead screw nut advances 8 mm every complete rotation of 200 full steps, so a single full step would change the height by 8/200 = 0.04 mm. This implies you need to set the layer height a multiple of 0.04 mm.

The gear ratio of 4:1 (a reduction) is required to get to your desired 0.01 mm layer height, but that is a very uncommon and a too small layer height to use.